# SQL Declaring Variables in a View

Tags: t-sql, variables, view, declare

I have created a view which uses dynamic variables in the where statement below.

```
DECLARE 
@wkFileYear SMALLINT = (select fs.FileYear from dbo.FileSemesters fs 
 where fs.systemcurrentflag = 1),
@wkFileSemester SMALLINT = (select fs.FileSemester from dbo.FileSemesters fs where fs.systemcurrentflag = 1)

Select R.FileType, R.FileYear, R.FileSemester, R.ID, R.ClassCode, R1.Raw
from
(
SELECT SC.FileType, SC.FileYear, SC.FileSemester, SC.ID, SC.ClassCode
FROM StudentClasses AS SC 
) as R
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT  SAR.Filetype,SAR.FileYear, SAR.FileSemester, SAR.ID, SAR.ClassCode, SAR.Result as Raw
FROM    
StudentAssessmentResults AS SAR
) as R1 

on r.FileYear = R1.Fileyear     
and R.FileSemester = R1.FileSemester
and R.FileType = R1.FileType
and R.ClassCode = R1. ClassCode
and R.ID = R1.ID        

where 
R.FileType = 'A'
AND (R.FileYear = @wkFileYear) 
AND (R.FileSemester = 
case 
when (left(R.classcode,2) = '12' or left(R.classcode,2) = '11') and @wkFileSemester = 4 
then 3
else @wkFileSemester
end
)
```

I would like to save this as a view in the database but you can't declare variables inside a view. I have looked at all the info on using CTEs or Table Valued Functions but am not sure at all of the syntax. I have tried creating the CTEs and Table Valued Functions using examples from various sources but no luck.

Was hoping that someone could explain how I could still use the variables but allow me to save this as a view in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not make sense for a view's structure to be dependent on variables.

Instead you need to make @wkFileYear and @wkFileSemester  columns in your view that you can query against.

Alternatively you could create a db function / stored procedure which returns the data you need, if you want to use variables.

Here's an example of what the stored proc might look like.

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetTestData]
            --Param
            @wkFileYear SMALLINT,
            @wkFileSemester SMALLINT
            AS
        BEGIN

        @wkFileYear = select fs.FileYear from dbo.FileSemesters fs where fs.systemcurrentflag = 1
        @wkFileSemester  = select fs.FileSemester from dbo.FileSemesters fs where fs.systemcurrentflag = 1

        Select R.FileType, R.FileYear, R.FileSemester, R.ID, R.ClassCode, R1.Raw
        from
        (
        SELECT SC.FileType, SC.FileYear, SC.FileSemester, SC.ID, SC.ClassCode
        FROM StudentClasses AS SC 
        ) as R
        LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  SAR.Filetype,SAR.FileYear, SAR.FileSemester, SAR.ID, SAR.ClassCode, SAR.Result as Raw
        FROM    
        StudentAssessmentResults AS SAR
        ) as R1 
        on r.FileYear = R1.Fileyear     
        and R.FileSemester = R1.FileSemester
        and R.FileType = R1.FileType
        and R.ClassCode = R1. ClassCode
        and R.ID = R1.ID where 
        R.FileType = 'A'
        AND (R.FileYear = @wkFileYear) 
        AND (R.FileSemester = 
        case 
        when (left(R.classcode,2) = '12' or left(R.classcode,2) = '11') and @wkFileSemester = 4 
        then 3
        else @wkFileSemester
        end
        )
        end
```

Comment: I did a join to the FileSemesters table within the view but found that this was much much slower for some reason. It was much faster when I hard coded a Year and Semester into the where statement, so this was why I wanted to try and carry them in as a variable rather than join to the FileSemesters table.

Comment: I've updated my answer with stored procedure example.

Answer (score 0):

You can *cheat* a little bit by using a CTE to resolve any variables that would like to declare. If the CTE for these *settings* only has a single row, then we can use a cross join to merge the *settings* so that they are available to each row in the view.

```
CREATE VIEW CurrentSemesterClasses 
AS

WITH SystemSettings as (
    -- Query to resolve the Variables, MUST only return a single row
    SELECT TOP 1 FileYear, FileSemester
    FROM dbo.FileSemesters
    WHERE SystemCurrentFlag = 1
)
SELECT R.FileType, R.FileYear, R.FileSemester, R.ID, R.ClassCode, R1.Raw
FROM StudentClasses R, SystemSettings
LEFT JOIN StudentAssessmentResults R1 
         ON R.FileYear = R1.Fileyear     
        and R.FileSemester = R1.FileSemester
        and R.FileType = R1.FileType
        and R.ClassCode = R1. ClassCode
        and R.ID = R1.ID
WHERE R.FileType = 'A'
  AND R.FileYear = SystemSettings.FileSemester
  AND R.FileSemester = CASE 
                            WHEN (left(R.classcode,2) = '12' or left(R.classcode,2) = '11') and SystemSettings.FileSemester = 4 then 3
                            ELSE SystemSettings.FileSemester
                       END
```

> **NOTE:** I have simplified your original query by referencing the required tables directly rather than using the strange sub-query that was used. This syntax should behave the same or have better performance than the original, but it ultimately much easier to maintain.
>
> There is no performance benefit to sub-querying just the columns that you think you need via sub-queries instead of joining directly onto tables. This syntax looks like you are expecting the sub-query to cache a subset of the data table but this is not how it works. Do not make the mistake of assuming the sub-query is resolved entirely first before the main query

In this particular case, if *by convention* or application logic there will only ever be a single row in the `dbo.FileSemesters` table that has `SystemCurrentFlag = 1` then we can further simplify this query to a simple join:

```
CREATE VIEW CurrentSemesterClassesSimple 
AS
SELECT R.FileType, R.FileYear, R.FileSemester, R.ID, R.ClassCode, R1.Raw
FROM StudentClasses R
INNER JOIN dbo.FileSemesters S ON R.FileYear = s.FileYear AND S.SystemCurrentFlag = 1
LEFT JOIN StudentAssessmentResults R1 
         ON R.FileYear = R1.Fileyear     
        and R.FileSemester = R1.FileSemester
        and R.FileType = R1.FileType
        and R.ClassCode = R1. ClassCode
        and R.ID = R1.ID
WHERE R.FileType = 'A'
  AND R.FileSemester = CASE 
                            WHEN (left(R.classcode,2) = '12' or left(R.classcode,2) = '11') and S.FileSemester = 4 then 3
                            ELSE S.FileSemester
                       END
```

To complete the set, the following is how you would package the cleaned up original query into a TVF - Table Valued Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION CurrentSemesterClassesFn
(
    -- This function has no parameters
)
RETURNS
@Table_Var TABLE
(
    -- Please update the types of these columns to match your schema!
      FileType CHAR(1)
    , FileYear INT
    , FileSemester INT
    , ID INT
    , ClassCode VARCHAR(100)
    , [Raw] VARCHAR(max)
)
CREATE VIEW CurrentSemesterClassesSimple 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @wkFileYear SMALLINT, @wkFileSemester SMALLINT;
SELECT @wkFileYear = fs.FileYear
     , @wkFileSemester = fs.FileSemester
FROM dbo.FileSemesters fs 
WHERE fs.systemcurrentflag = 1;

INSERT INTO @Table_Var (FileType, FileYear, FileSemester, ID, ClassCode, Raw)
SELECT R.FileType, R.FileYear, R.FileSemester, R.ID, R.ClassCode, R1.Raw
FROM StudentClasses R
LEFT JOIN StudentAssessmentResults R1 
         ON R.FileYear = R1.Fileyear     
        and R.FileSemester = R1.FileSemester
        and R.FileType = R1.FileType
        and R.ClassCode = R1. ClassCode
        and R.ID = R1.ID
WHERE R.FileType = 'A'
  AND R.FileYear = @wkFileYear
  AND R.FileSemester = CASE 
                            WHEN (left(R.classcode,2) = '12' or left(R.classcode,2) = '11') and @wkFileSemester = 4 then 3
                            ELSE S.FileSemester
                       END

    RETURN
END
```